# Rails Nested Fields With Cocoon - link_to_add_association is Deleting Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, cocoon-gem, accepts-nested-attributes

I'm using nested fields and accept nested attributes with a 3 level nested relationship. The 3rd level (I don't think it matters that it's third level) relationship gets deleted when editing the parent.

Setup has one material, material has one rotap_analysis, rotap_analysis has many rotap_sieves. The following code is what triggers the delete ONLY WHEN EDITING AN EXISTING SETUP THAT ALREADY HAS A ROTAP ANALYSIS, creating new or editing and creating new rotap analysis works fine:

```
  <%= f.fields_for :rotap_analysis do |ra| %>
    <%= render 'materials/rotap_analysis_fields', f: ra %>
  <% end %> 
  <div class="links float-e-margins">
  <!-- this is deleting rotap analysis -->
    <%= link_to_add_association '+ rotap analysis', f, :rotap_analysis, partial: 'materials/rotap_analysis_fields', class: "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
  </div>
```

Here is the server log with the delete transactions upon rendering with "fields_for" helper.

```
RotapAnalysis Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "rotap_analyses".* FROM "rotap_analyses" WHERE "rotap_analyses"."material_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["material_id", 23], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/views/materials/_material_fields.html.erb:77
  RotapSieve Load (4.2ms)  SELECT "rotap_sieves".* FROM "rotap_sieves" WHERE "rotap_sieves"."rotap_analysis_id" = $1  [["rotap_analysis_id", 18]]
  ↳ app/views/materials/_rotap_analysis_fields.html.erb:24
  Rendered materials/_rotap_sieve_fields.html.erb (Duration: 1.0ms | Allocations: 488)
  Rendered materials/_rotap_sieve_fields.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 475)
  Rendered materials/_rotap_analysis_fields.html.erb (Duration: 13.0ms | Allocations: 2823)
  TRANSACTION (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/views/materials/_material_fields.html.erb:82
  RotapSieve Destroy (0.4ms)  DELETE FROM "rotap_sieves" WHERE "rotap_sieves"."id" = $1  [["id", 17]]
  ↳ app/views/materials/_material_fields.html.erb:82
  RotapAnalysis Destroy (0.5ms)  DELETE FROM "rotap_analyses" WHERE "rotap_analyses"."id" = $1  [["id", 18]]
  ↳ app/views/materials/_material_fields.html.erb:82
  TRANSACTION (1.0ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/views/materials/_material_fields.html.erb:82
  Rendered materials/_rotap_sieve_fields.html.erb (Duration: 0.9ms | Allocations: 475)
  Rendered materials/_rotap_analysis_fields.html.erb (Duration: 4.2ms | Allocations: 1495)
  Rendered materials/_material_fields.html.erb (Duration: 43.9ms | Allocations: 12427)
  Rendered setups/_form.html.erb (Duration: 123.8ms | Allocations: 42184)
  Rendered setups/edit.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 124.1ms | Allocations: 42245
```

I have several nested attributes throughout the application and I have never ran into this issue. What the heck is going on?

Comment: Looks to be a duplicate, albeit with a more descriptive title: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25870978/3390279

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [documented](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon#has-one-gotcha) this is weird but well known behaviour when using a `has_one` relationship. By default cocoon uses the association to create the new nested item.
But then rails assumes, if you already have one, creating a new one will replace it (which does make sense).

However: when using the `link_to_add_association` we pre-create an empty item to fill, so it will always delete it.

There is a simple workaround: for `has_one` associations you can use the `force_non_association_create: true` which will not create the child element using the association, and thus will not remove existing items (for `has_one` associations).

So in your case you would write:

```
<%= link_to_add_association '+ rotap analysis', f, :rotap_analysis, 
       partial: 'materials/rotap_analysis_fields', 
       force_non_association_create: true, 
       class: "btn btn-info btn-xs" %>
```

Comment: I did stumble into this on your documentation shortly after posting the question. I'm glad I found a good resolution! I do agree, it's very strange that DELETEs are occurring while initiating a get request for the edit page. Good now, thx.